# Отображение элементов на Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

У меня есть Активити на котором, в зависимости от введенных параметров, рисуется график. Опорные точки этого графика можно двигать и т.п. Вот примерно так это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, я думаю, что содержание методов не особо важно, поэтому вот всё, что я использую:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawView(this));
}

//анимация для открытия этой Активити
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}}

class DrawView extends View {
//создаю все необходимые константы и переменные
Paint p;
Paint p2;


public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    //задаем перо для рисования
    p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p2 = new Paint(p);
    p2.setStrokeWidth(4);
    p2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p2.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{30, 10}, 0));
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Рисую линии, кружочки, буковки и получается рисунок со скриншота
}

//Двигаю точки
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float X = event.getX();
    float Y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Если попал в пределы точки, то можно двигать
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // запрещаем двигать другие точки и перерисовываем нажатую

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}}
```

xml- файл я вообще не трогал.

В чем же проблема?
Мне нужно на этом Активити разместить `EditText` , чтобы я мог ввести туда параметры и график перерисовался, а когда я начинал двигать точки графика, то чтобы менялись значения в полях ввода. Конечно, желательно, чтобы все это происходило сразу, без каких либо нажатий кнопок и т.п. Пока что проблема не в том как совершать передачу данных и перерасчет, а в том, как эти элементы разместить на Активити?!?

Какое решение есть у меня в голове. Их два.

1) Сделать так, чтобы `Canvas` занимал не весь экран, а только, например, половину экрана, а `EditText` разместить на лейауте, например. Читал много про `Bitmap` , но как я понял, сам битмап предназначен для того, чтобы поместить что-то на канву, а не размещать канву в своих, заранее заданных, пределах.

2) Отображать элементы прямо на канве. Но простым способом, типо инициализации по id, как вы понимаете, не обойтись.

Вот так вот. К сожалению, я совершенно не понимаю как реализовать это.

Comment: Такого элемента как canvas нет. Есть View который можно перерисовать в методе onDraw. Соответственно можно использовать любую разметку с вашим custom View, например FrameLayout, под низ ваш custom View а сверху все что угодно

Comment: @Style-7 Ты имеешь ввиду использовать мой "рисунок" как бэкграунд? А я смогу с ним взаимодействовать?

Comment: не ты а вы, причем тут рисунок вообще, могу лишь порекомендовать хотя бы какую-нибудь книгу прочесть

Comment: @Style-7 Извините. Вы не могли чуть подробнее рассказать, что именно мне сделать? Я не совсем понимаю как это "под низ". Или, может быть, подскажите источник, где я подробно могу об этом прочитать.

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/framelayout.php